# How to rearrange data to Column, Column to Row, and Row to data

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

[Here's the picture of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgjHU.png)

I have a data in the first table, rearranged as so, but I want my data to look like the second table. I'm still getting responses, so as Table 1 get's larger, I want Table 2 to continously update the data. Would I do this with a pivot table? Do I have to update my first data table before I put in a pivot table?

[Here's the google sheet if you need the data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bfZ2mp_5TFGT73NnQqmDJ6fWZ-b57sw1R5jHGUYEUmQ/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A21:A24,lambda(Σ,bycol(B20:G20,lambda(Λ,join(",",ifna(filter(A3:A8,regexmatch(filter(B3:E8,B2:E2=Σ),Λ))))))))
```

[image]